# How do I change the foreground color of text in a JavaFX TextArea dynamically?

Tags: javafx, textarea

I am using JavaFX 8 and have a read-only TextArea that displays either a confirmation message or an error message, depending on the situation. I want confirmation messages to have black text but I want error messages to have red text. How do I do that in JavaFX 8? For the moment, I'd prefer to do it programmatically but I would certainly be interested in how that could be done in FXML as well for the next draft of the program.

Essentially, I am displaying a tableView and letting the user edit the information in the cells of the TableView. If the user puts an invalid value in the cell, I want to give him/her a clear error message about what's wrong and I'd like that message to be red (or highlighted in some way). If they change the value in an acceptable way, I want a confirmation message that tells them they've changed the value successfully in the table and the database; I'd prefer that message is black (or similar).

I'm fairly new to JavaFX and am surprised to find that there is no setForeground() any more. How are we supposed to do this now? Or should I be using some kind of HTML field? I haven't played with those yet....

=======================================================================
Followup question

I may be misunderstanding the intent of James_D's answer but I created TWO pseudoclasses, one for error messages and one for informational messages:

```
private static final PseudoClass ERROR =                               PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error");

private static final PseudoClass INFO = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("info");
```

I had hoped to be able to have a simple method that could write EITHER kind of message, informational or error, simply by passing the pseudoclass to the method. Here's the method:

```
private void writeMessage(String message, PseudoClass pseudoClass) {

    messageArea.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, true);
    messageArea.setText(message);
}
```

I invoke the method as follows for an error message:

```
writeMessage("This is an error message.", ERROR);
```

and this way for an information message:

```
writeMessage("This is an information message.", INFO);
```

And this is what I added to my CSS file:

```
.text-area:error {
-fx-text-fill: red ;
-fx-font-weight: 700;
}   

.text-area:info {
-fx-text-fill: black;
-fx-font-weight: normal;
 }
```

Why don't my error messages show up as bold? (All messages appear in normal font.) Why do some error messages not show up as red? I consistently invoke writeMessage() the same way throughout.

Comment: If you want black and red text to be present in the text area at the same time, then that can't be done with a text area. Maybe consider using an [`HTMLEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html). If you only need one or the other, use `setStyle(...)`. Clarify an I can offer a more complete answer.

Comment: I just need one foreground color at a time. At least that's my initial conception; that could change.

Comment: Do you every switch either of the pseudo classes off? While this approach could work, it's probably overly complicated. If there are only two possibilities, you only need one pseudoclass. The two CSS selectors you need are `.text-area{   }` and `.text-area:error {.  }`. If there are more than two possibilities, then you may need more pseudoclasses, but your logic must ensure all pseudoclass states are set to the correct value.

Comment: [Sorry for the delay in replying; I didn't see your comment at first.] I'm probably not doing a very good job of switching the pseudo classes off. I didn't know I needed to! In addition to the writeMessage() method I quoted, I also have a clearMessage() that merely erases the contents of the message textArea and sets the font-weight back to normal but it doesn't invoke the pseudo class; it sounds like it should.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaFX, you style controls using CSS. The recommended way is to use an external style sheet, which separates the style (in the CSS file) from the logic (in Java). You can also use an "inline" style by directly calling `setStyle(...)` on a control.

According to the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol), `TextArea`s have a CSS property `-fx-text-fill` which defines the color of the text that is displayed.

So the "quick and dirty" way could be:

```
private TextArea messageArea ;

// ...

private void showMessage(String message, boolean error) {
    if (error) {
        messageArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red ;") ;
    } else {
        messageArea.setStyle("");
    }
    messageArea.setText(message);
}
```

A better approach is to define your own CSS [`PseudoClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html), and then to reference it in an external style sheet:

```
private static final PseudoClass ERROR = PseudoClass.getPsuedoClass("error");

private TextArea messageArea ;

// ...

private void showMessage(String message, boolean error) {
    messageArea.pseudoClassStateChanged(ERROR, error);
    messageArea.setText(message);
}
```

Your CSS file can now define how error messages are styled:

```css
.text-area:error {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

and then you can attach the stylesheet to the scene with

```
Scene scene = ... ;
scene.getStylesheets().add("path/to/css/file");
```

Comment: Thanks James_D! The "quick and dirty" method works great. I almost had that part of it working from your earlier clue to use setStyle() but my syntax was slightly off so my CSS got ignored. Also, I just learned that I can put multiple directives in the setStyle() argument by separating them with semi-colons, just like I do in "real" CSS files, e.g. messageArea.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: 700; -fx-text-fill: red"). If I make those two separate lines, only the later one takes effect. Now I'm going to try the better way....

Comment: Yes, of course. If you set the style multiple times, then the style will hold the last value you set it to, just like setting any other property. If you have more than one style property to set, which you almost certainly will, then updating the pseudoclass and delegating all the style settings to the CSS file will be much cleaner.

Comment: I'm trying the preferred method and it *almost* works, but not quite. I'll detail the bigger problem elsewhere on this page but the smaller problem is that I have two style changes in my CSS, changing the fill color to Red and the font-weight to 700 for errors and back to black/normal for informational messages. However, the font-weight seems to be getting ignored, even though it follows normal CSS coding rules. Why would that be? Here's the code: .text-area:error {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
    -fx-font-weight: 700;
}

Comment: It works for me... not sure. I vaguely remember font weights not behaving correctly some time ago. Is your JDK version up to date?

Comment: Good question about the JDK version but I'm not actually sure. I'm using Eclipse (Mars 4.5.2) and my JRE System Library says "[JavaSE-1.8]" but every one of the jars in the Library says "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib". Yet I seem to have all the JavaFX8 components. I'm really not sure why all of these jars are in a directory named jre7....

Answer (score 0):

`textArea.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);` works for me.